# How do I collect and store current user's Longitude and Latitude?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

What is the simplest way to collect an User's current location in latitude and longitude on their mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Everything explained in [Xamarin Help](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/).

First, you need to declare the permissions necessary to use the LocationServices. For example:

[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]

---

The method GetSystemService(LocationService) will give you 'LocationManager' object, which in-turn can give you coordinates based on device's GPS. Use these coordinates as your wish.

---

After this, implement 'ILocationListener' interface in your Activity class. ILocationListener will implement:

```
public void OnLocationChanged(Location location) {}

public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider) {}

public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider) {}

public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras) {}
```

Use these methods as per your application's need.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Xamarin component: https://components.xamarin.com/view/geolocatorplugin

It's cross platform so you don't have to implement it on iOS and Android.